# Udev rule- change group

Tags: linux, nvidia, group, udev

I would like to change group of `/dev/nvidia0`. I was write udev rule:

`KERNEL="nvidia[0-9]", GROUP="video", MODE="0666"`

But it does't change group, after reboot file is in `root`group. How do this?

Comment: I do this but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Typo mistake, use **`==`** for match and **`=`** for assignment. So your rule should be:

```
KERNEL=="nvidia[0-9]", GROUP="video", MODE="0666"
```